# Vuelidate is not working while import in vue 3

Tags: vuejs3, vuelidate

[image]

[image]

[image]

vuelidate vue 2 is working fine but vue 3 is not working I can't able to use the vulidate package into main.ts file

if I try to import directly to the component without importing vuelidate into main.ts file getting this error

this project is vue 3 + class based component + typescript

if I directly use the vuelidate package I get this error
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QmaD1.png

Comment: Hi, code images are not allowed here. Please update your question with actual code as text.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557)